# Full screen images regardless of aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

Is there a way or a plugin to make an image fill the screen like with Fancybox.  Like one that automatically crop, centers, and scales the image?

Comment: Why not use Fancybox, if I may ask?

Answer (score 1):

```
body { 
background: url(images/sample.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```